# Is there a way to make superfish plugin same height of the menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sass, superfish

I'm using [superfish](https://superfish.joelbirch.design/examples/) jquery plugin. I'm trying to make the second submenu to have the same height as the first submenu. I also want to position the second submenu just under the menu as indicated in the screenshot. But i don't know how to do it. I've tried making the parent as display: contents but if I do that everything just stops working
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved by adding just two css-rule.

By default all submenus (i.e. the `<ul>`s) are absolutely positioned with respect to the parent `<li>` element. So, to make the third level submenu positioned with respect to the top level menu, unset `position: relative;` on all second level `<li>`s:

```
.sf-menu ul li {
    position: unset;
}
```

To make the second submenu at least as high as the first submenu, you can set `min-height` on the second submenu's `ul`:

```
.sf-menu ul li ul {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

You might want to set the background color on that css rule or do some further styling to fit your needs.

Comment: thanks its working now, and how do i put them in the same height like is they were a single block?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. The height of the second submenu depends on the number of list-items it has and their height. 
Could you try to explain a bit better what you are after?

Comment: In the case that the first <ul> would have 5 elements and se second <ul> (its child) has 3 elements we have 5-3. the height of the first <ul> will be higer than the second one, i want to match the second <uls> height just like the parent